# What is the maximum clients a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ access point can handle?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, pi-zero-w

I have setup a RPi 3B+ as access point using this tutorial:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

I have a few dozens of RPi Zero's that connect to the AP. The problem is that, when the AP has 15+ clients, it becomes unresponsive. New clients are not able to join.

I am not sure if I have to change anything in the configurations to make it work. The current setup is identical to the tutorial above. Or is it simply a hardware limitation that has no solution?

Comment: I notice in that example that the dnsmasq config only has a pool of 18 IP addresses to hand out. That's going to limit the number of clients. Whether that's the limit you're hitting I don't know.

Comment: I changed dnsmasq to support 255 clients.

Comment: And did it help?

Comment: No. I already had it changed. There is no solution, I think. Even many commercial APs have a limit of 15-20 clients...

Comment: @Roman Semko - have you found any workaround? I have 26+ ESP8266 to connect to RPi3B+ and currently max I've seen connected were 15...

Comment: @AidasJanulis no, ended up working with an ad hoc network. this has its downsides, since the more traffic flows through, the more "chattier" everyone becomes. ^^